# How do I use MSTest without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

Does MSTest have standalone GUI similar to nUnit that lets me use it and run test without visual studio? What is the official site for MSTest where I can learn more about how to use it?

Comment: Related post - [Can I use mstest.exe without installing Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3402899/465053)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't have a GUI (apart from Visual Studio) but there's a command line tool: [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)

Here is the official documentation on [running MSTest tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182469.aspx).

Comment: @mark - but that's a lot of work to get your tests to run on a build server :)

Comment: I have a two parts reply. The first part is that you do it onc and the benefit is that the build server remains clean - no VS installed. The second part is that this was the least significant problem we had with mstest. Other problems - inability to have dynamic and combinatorial tests forced us to abandon mstest and adopt MbUnit/Gallio and we have never regretted that decision.

Comment: @mark - thanks for sharing your war story. Nice info. I have always felt no reason to move from Nunit to mstest.. but the org. powers think otherwise.

Comment: @Gishu - You are welcome. I strongly advise you to convince whoever is in charge to use Gallio/MbUnit. It is a much more mature framework than mstest. Plus its VS addin seamlessly integrates with all the standard VS Test windows, so you can still run all the unit tests from within the IDE. Do not repeat our mistakes.

Comment: There's now a [console runner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182486.aspx).

Comment: @mark Does your opinion still apply regarding Gallio in 2020? It seems to be rather dead as a project.  Site not been updated since ... 2012/2013? (https://github.com/Gallio)

Comment: @W.Prins - Nope. Gallio is dead, as you noted. I am now using .Net Core with the standard Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk which with the proper adapter can run xUnit and NUnit and MSTest v2 and that is good enough for me. It does not require VS, only the VS build tools, which is fine. All the dependencies are NuGet packages. So, no problem anymore.

Answer (score 40):

MSTest can be used without installing Visual Studio. You will need to [install Visual Studio Test Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents), which is a free download from Microsoft.

I think this approach is better from a licensing perspective than manually copying MSTest.exe and its dependencies onto the build server.

See this blog for reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/2009/12/16/running-tests-in-mstest-without-installing-the-vs-ide.aspx

Comment: There are chocolatey packages for both the `visualstudio2013testagents` and `visualstudio2015testagents` which should install to the correct locations for your CI system (TeamCity/Jenkins) or other tools to use.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with mstest.exe, but the trick is in getting it to work without installing visual studio. This involves the copying of several files and registry entries. I have blogged about it [here](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2008/11/executing-visual-studio-unit-tests.html).

Comment: Nice trick ... the complexity of the process is an argument to write tests in NUnit :)

Comment: Thanks, the post is really helpful.
You've published the update to that post, which includes batch script to create a 'deployable mstest package', in case someone doesn't notice that on your site, here's the link: http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2011/02/executing-visual-studio-2010-unit-tests.html

Answer (score 5):

Use [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) as your test runner... then its not so much of a drama when you enventually drop MsTest and move to a real test framework.

Comment: Gallio still requires MSTest to be installed separately. This doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: um, yes it does. "Does MSTest have standalone GUI similar to nUnit that lets me use it and run test without visual studio?"
I run tests without VS all the time with Gallio. The question is with regard to VS, not MsTest. Running test outside of VS is much faster and leads you to be CI practices

Comment: This is an awesome tool. Works just like NUnit UI.

Answer (score 5):

Use **VSTest.console.exe** part of **Microsoft.TestPlatform**

Required steps:

1. Download the test platform from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform/
2. Unzip
3. In the unzipped folder, copy the *\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform* folder to the machine that has no Visual Studio installed
4. From cmd.exe run **VSTest.console.exe MyTest.dll**

More details here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017#general-command-line-options

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this tool from codeplex: http://testrunner.codeplex.com...

Comment: Doesn't support .NET 4.0 yet. Do you know if there is a similar tool that supports .NET 4.0?

Comment: They updated this in 2012 to support tests written in .Net 4.0 :)

Comment: The TestRunner project moved to here: https://github.com/macro187/testrunner

Answer (score 0):

Uset "dotnet test", it is compatible with all versions, eg:

```
'dotnet test yourassembly.dll -l console -v detailed'
```