# Create a stand-alone executable out of VS2008 test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

Is it possible to run an assembly created by a Visual Studio test project outside Visual Studio itself?
I would like to create a test application **that should be run also on machines where VS is not installed**, and get a (graphical) report of the test outcomes.

**EDIT** looking at the post provided in the accepted answer, and looking at the answer to that post... I reached the conclusion that the answer to this question is "NUnit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [MsTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(VS.80).aspx) command line.  You can either use it or roll your own code as a test harness around the assemblies.  But if you want the GUI and to legally use MSTEST you will need a license for Visual Studio on the machine you will run the tests on.

You can use [MsTest without VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio).  but I don't know how "legal" that is so it's at your own risk

Comment: That's exactly what I would need... but the executable is installed along with the VS test tools, right? So I would still need VS installed on the target machine...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is this possible like you describe it.

If you are using Team Foundation Server you can create Report to display status of your latest Continuous integration (or Nightly) build where you can display test results in any way you want.

One example is here:
[image: TFS report]
<sub>(source: [edsquared.com](http://www.edsquared.com/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/QualityIndicatorsReportforConchangoScrum_E0D5/healthy_qualityindicators_thumb.gif))</sub>

In this way anybody can access and view these test results via a web browser, Visual Studio, or Team System Web Access (which is again web browser). So users with and without Visual Studio get the same view on the report.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the purpose is not to allow users without VS installed on their machine to see the results, but to run the test program on a machine without VS installed.