# ASP.NET MSTest Runner to run unit test via browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, sitecore6

We are building a sitecore web application and unit test is based on MSTest. I had a look at link below which has asp.net nunit test runner:
http://www.codeflood.net/testrunner/

However, we don't want to use the nUnit framework for out of box MSTest suit. Could someone please help if there's any existing test runner or how easy it is to convert the nUnit Test runner to MSTest runner?

The reason we want to use the test runner is to run unit test with in HTTPContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054994/is-there-an-api-for-running-visual-studio-unit-tests-programmatically) the API used by MSTest is sealed and private which is not going to help you in exposing a test runner that mimics the NUnit TestSuiteBuilder functionality.

It could still be done via Reflection if you are determined enough but it might just be simpler to use the technical restrictions around MSTest to build a case to migrate your unit tests that require a Sitecore context to NUnit.