# Start unit test from a webpage and display result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Is it possible to start a unit test from a webpage inside the webproject and show the result (FAILED - PASSED) after the test back on the webpage?
I need to build something like that with ASP.Net MVC, C# and Unit tests.
Can't seem to find a lot of info about it on the internet.
The url should be something like this: http://mywebsite.com/Status

Comment: Did you took a look into Jenkins? There are Plugins for it, allowing to build/test .net projects.

Comment: If you say you couldn't find anything, it helps to show what you searched for. See [Is there an API for running Visual Studio Unit Tests programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054994/is-there-an-api-for-running-visual-studio-unit-tests-programmatically).

Comment: What Unit test framework are you using? This is easily done with Nunit, but I am unsure with MSTest

Comment: @JamieRees, I can use Nunit if that is what is needed. But how would I go about it to start the test from a status page?

Comment: Nunit supports running tests from cmd line parameters. you would also need to provide the test dll and dependencies.