# can I run C# built-in unit test in build machine?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

can I run C# built-in unit test in build machine which doesn't have Visual Studio installed?
We are thinking add unit test to our Visual Studio 2008 C# project. Our build machine doesn't have VS installed and we want to integrate the new unit test with our auto-build system. Is MSTest the executable to launch the Team Test unit test?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSTest.exe  [MSTest.exe Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) or maybe [gallio](http://www.gallio.org/Default.aspx)