# Programmatically finding the VS2017 installation directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

With previous versions of VS you could query the registry to determine the installation directory for VS:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

However, this doesn't seem to work with the VS2017 RC. We have scripts that detect the latest installed VS and then do "the right thing", and so far I'm having issues plugging VS2017 into those systems.

Does anyone know how to programmatically determine the installation location for VS2017?

Comment: Applications are *not* supposed to use the `Wow` nodes. They only exist in x64 systems to allow x86 applications to work. Have you checked the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\Setup` node? Anyway, the disk layout has changed a *lot*. Almost everything can be found in the `%PROGRAM FILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\` now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`vswhere`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/releases) tool to get VS2017 location.

Example:

```bsh
@echo off

rem VS2017U2 contains vswhere.exe
if "%VSWHERE%"=="" set "VSWHERE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"%VSWHERE%" -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath`) do (
  set InstallDir=%%i
)

if exist "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" (
  "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" %*
)
```

You can read more about it here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/02/25/vswhere-available/

Comment: I'm swapping to this one as the accepted answer as it provides me with an example of how I can script to get the path.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me - see the changes I needed to do in my answer.

Comment: This works if `vswhere` is on the path by default which it isn't. See @Srekel's answer below...

Comment: vswhere is a self contained exe so you can always copy it to where ever you want

Comment: "%VSWHERE%" -latest might not be the best idea if you have both VS2017 and VS2019 installed; you can try "%VSWHERE%" -version [15.0,16.0) though to pinpoint to VS2017

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2017 supports no-registry, side-by-side installations of all SKUs (Enterprise, Professional and Community).

MSI installlers can query via APIs described here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2016/09/15/changes-to-visual-studio-15-setup/

Examples are here:

- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Setup-0cedd331
- https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples

Comment: I figured it was some kind of side-by-side thing - thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

KindDragon's solution didn't quite work for me due to batch's "delayed expansion" "feature". (WAT)

Here is my code, compatible with VS 2017 15.2 (for the vswhere.exe installation)

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" (
  echo "WARNING: You need VS 2017 version 15.2 or later (for vswhere.exe)"
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath`) do (
  set InstallDir=%%i
)

if exist "!InstallDir!\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" (
  call "!InstallDir!\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
) else (
  echo "Could not find !InstallDir!\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)
```

Especially note usage of SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion and !InstallDir!

Comment: I don't see how delayed expansion factors in to KindDragon's solution - it would only be relevant if the "set" and "get" of the environment variable were nested within a single statement... as it stands his solution works for me

Comment: I dunno man. I pasted it into my batch file and it didn't work, seemingly because it didn't expand the InstallDir variable at runtime. Then I used EnabledDelayedExpansion and it worked for me. I abhor batch files and wasn't too keen on understanding what went wrong and am happy to just have found a solution :D Posted it in hopes that it might help someone else.

Comment: This snippet actually works because it doesn't presume `vswhere` is on the path. For those wondering about the delayed expansion, all it does is enable expansion of variables using the `!somevar!` syntax within looping and conditional blocks. The currently accepted answer by @KindDragon doesn't use delayed expansion so I presume @Srekel is referring to his own construct not working without it.

Comment: IIRC, the problem arose when trying to actually use the InstallDir variable. Without delayed expansions, using it with the traditional % lookup doesn't work because then it has the value it has at the beginning of the batch file - i.e. nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *vswhere.exe* doesn't really supply more than the Visual Studio edition installation path. Here's my .profile file Interix snippet from 2008 doing the same with a minor update (shell script):

```
if [[ -n $PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 || $PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE != "x86" ]]; then
  hkeybase='HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\'
else
  hkeybase='HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'
fi
for vsver in "15.0" "14.0" "12.0" "11.0" "10.0" "9.0" "8.0"; do
  _vsinstalldir=$(reg.exe query ${hkeybase}'VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' -v $vsver 2>/dev/null \
   | sed -n 's|.*REG_SZ *\([ [:print:]]*\).*|\1|p' | sed 's|\\|/|g')
if [[ -n $_vsinstalldir ]]; then break; fi
done; unset vsver
```

That's enumerating Visual Studio installations favouring the latest in registry key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7
```

Still working for Visual Studio 2017. Would be easy to translate to cmd syntax. To query the registry is simpler and doesn't require vswhere.exe in your path, thus favourable IMO.

Now finding the current Visual C++ instance and the SDKs is another task entirely. :D

Common output in case you wonder:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a devil of time trying to modify Srekel's answer to search for only VS2017. Note: If you put the "for" statement below inside an "if" block it will wreck the escape characters and won't work.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" (
  echo "WARNING: You need VS 2017 version 15.2 or later (for vswhere.exe)"
)

set vswherestr=^"!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe^" -version [15.0,16.0^^) -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`!vswherestr!`) do (  
  set BUILDVCTOOLS=%%i\Common7\Tools
  echo BUILDVCTOOLS: !BUILDVCTOOLS!
  if not exist !BUILDVCTOOLS!\VsDevCmd.bat (
    echo Error: Cannot find VS2017 Build Tools
    goto :buildfailed
  )
  call "!BUILDVCTOOLS!\VsDevCmd.bat"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend my package [get-vs2017-path](https://github.com/node4good/get-vs2017-path) it uses only built-in Windows tools (and although it's built as an `NPM` package, it has no dependencies, and the tools folder works standalone)

Answer (score 0):

See following answer in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754831/2338477

You can use either command line tool for querying Visual studio location, but I also provide programmatic way to query Visual Studio location. Code is based upon `vswhere` source code, but simplified.

Answer (score 0):

We have only 3 Visual Studio editions.

- \Community
- \Professional
- \Enterprise

As such we can simplify everything a bit.
Here some tested CMD script.

```sh
@SET env_all_vs2017_root=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
@SET env_vs2017_path="%env_all_vs2017_root%\Professional"
@IF NOT EXIST %env_vs2017_path%  SET env_vs2017_path="%env_all_vs2017_root%\Community"
@IF NOT EXIST %env_vs2017_path%  SET env_vs2017_path="%env_all_vs2017_root%\Enterprise"
@REM Let's fail laudly
@IF NOT EXIST %env_vs2017_path%  SET "env_vs2017_path=Visual Studio 2017 install path was not found by %~nx0"

@REM  You may want to remove quotes
@SET unquoted=%env_vs2017_path:"=%


@REM  And now let's see the result and PAUSE

@ECHO VS 2017 install path is
@ECHO %unquoted%

@PAUSE
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this PowerShell snippet for finding the VS2017 installation directory:

```bsh
$vssetup_path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\VSSetup"
if (-not (Test-Path $vssetup_path -pathType container))
{
    iwr https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell/releases/download/1.0.36-rc/VSSetup.zip -OutFile "$env:TEMP\VSSetup.zip"
    Expand-Archive "$env:TEMP\VSSetup.zip" $vssetup_path
}
$vs2017 = Get-VSSetupInstance -All | Select-VSSetupInstance -Require 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop' -Version '[15.0,16.0)' -Latest
"Installation Path: " + $vs2017.InstallationPath
#`vsdevcmd.bat -arch=x86` or `vsdevcmd.bat -arch=amd64` can be used to setup path's to VC++ compiler
"VsDevCmd.bat Path: " + $vs2017.InstallationPath + "\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

Comment: Hey, you tried to sneak the module into my system . Anyway it failed on my system... `(-not (Test-Path $vssetup_path -pathType container)) -eq 0` so the module did not install

Answer (score -3):

I use powershell like KindDragon suggested

```bsh
$Is64bitOs = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq 'AMD64';
if ($Is64bitOs){
    $registryPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0";
}
else {
    $registryPath = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0";
}

$VSInstallDir = (Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 -Name ShellFolder).ShellFolder;
```

Comment: It's path to VS2015, not 2017

Comment: I'm not sure about the new VS2017 version, but possibly change 14.0 to 15.0?

Comment: No, VS2017 don't use registry