# How to enable TFS tracing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I was looking to enable TFS tracing in my Visual Studio 2017.  All the links I have found is for older version of Visial Studio where you go to the \common7\IDE directory to open up the devenv.exe.config file.  For some reason, I do not have this file in my 2017 version.

Does Visual Studio 2017 still utilize the devenev.exe.config?  If so, does it reside in a different directory from previous versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going to the VS 2017 environment in a command window in administrator mode.  I then ran 'devenv.exe /log c:\vs_logs\log.txt'.  That allowed me to create logs of what VS was doing

Answer (score 0):

The `devenev.exe` is also located under `\common7\IDE` directory. However, VS2017 **installed path is not the same** as previous version. The `devenv.exe` is located at:

***For VS2017***

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

***For VS2015***

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

If you want to find  the install location of `devenv` in a script, [since there is no %VS150COMNTOOLS% for Visual Studio 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/13223/no-environmental-variable-vscomntools150.html), you could use `vswhere.exe` or powershell to find your Visual Studio instances. Detail steps please refer this question: [reliable way to find the location devenv.exe of Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713238/reliable-way-to-find-the-location-devenv-exe-of-visual-studio-2017)