# How to retrieve VS2017 installed location from Registry?

Tags: c#, registry, visual-studio-2017

I can retrieve the VS installed location till **`VS2015`** from this Registry key `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{Version}"`.

**For Ex**: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`

But there is no registry entry like this for **`VS2017`**. So how can i retrieve the installed location for **`VS2017`** from registry ?

Comment: See also "[Programmatically finding the VS2017 installation directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41106407/1364007)" which offers more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the design changes in VS2017, you can only use official tools such as [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) to locate the folder.