# Can I run my microsoft unit tests outside of visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a bunch of microsoft unit tests in several of my apps and have done some looking on here and other places to see if I could run these tests without installing visual studio on my client's computers which is not a possibility. So the simple question is - can I run the tests through some test harness on the client's computer?

Comment: Unit test are a developer/build tool and not normally run on user's computers. Why do you even want to run them there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use mstest.exe without installing Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio)