# Using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to build an open source project in Sharpdevelop, but the tests don't compile as it references the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace.

I don't have Visual Studio (not even the Express editions).  Is there any way to compile this project without Visual Studio (and without changing the code to use NUnit)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use MSTest without Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio)

Comment: @Gishu yes, I saw that question but it deals with the GUI rather than trying to build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, because as you can see from the namespace, MS Test framework relies on Visual Studio.

Comment: but is this particular namespace to be found in a standalone dll library which MS provides for download on MSDN?

Comment: No because MS wants you to buy Visual Studio.

Comment: +1. Note that MSTest not really depends on Visual Studio, but it does depend on a few DLLs that only come with Visual Studio. You could copy those DLLs (and the MSTest.exe) and check them in in your own branch, but I'm not sure what the legal consequences are :-). It's best to switch to an open source testing framework such as NUnit.

Comment: I've found a few helpful links in response to another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio