# MS Unit Testing Framework without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, msbuild

We are using the MS Unit Testing Framework from Visual Studio 2010. At the moment we are implementing continuous integration and we have a dedicated build machine.

The problem is we don't want to install Visual Studio 2010 on a build server but only MSBuild which is enough for building our project. However the MS Unit Testing Framework is part of Visual Studio 2010.

Can we install the MS Unit Testing Framework on the build machine with installing the VS2010 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use MSTest without Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allegedly [Gallio](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3) supports running MS Test unit tests and comes with it's own command line and GUI test runner (you'll probably be more interested in the command line one).  You could try to run your tests through that.

There was also this link in the comments in the other question [Running mstest without Visual Studio.](http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/23/running-mstest-without-visual-studio/)

---

**Update**
As of Visual Studio 2012, there's a [command line runner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182486.aspx).

> VSTest.Console.exe You can use the VSTest.Console.exe program to run
>   automated unit and coded UI tests from a command line.
>   VSTest.Console.exe is optimized for performance and is used in place
>   of MSTest.exe in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: It should, at worst it should take you to code.google.com where you see a notice about the project moving to Github.  I updated the link just in case though.