# Getting custom attributes using reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reflection

I am building a utility to run the unit test cases, where the user will be provided with the option to select the test they want to run. I am using reflection to get the methods. But it is not working

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("TestingAssembly");
var classes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestClassAttribute), false).Length > 0);
 foreach (var type in classes)
 {
   var methods= type.GetTypes().Where(m1 => m1.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false).Length > 0);
 }
```

The classes object is always empty. If I iterate through the assembly.GetTypes and get the custom attributes it is returning the count. But still, I am not able to match it. In the below code the attributes contains an item with is TestClassAttribute. But when am matching the attribute's type to TestClassAttribute it fails.

```
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
  if (type.GetCustomAttributes().Count() > 0)
   {
     var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes();
       foreach (var item in attributes)
       {
         if (item.GetType() == Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute)
         {
            //Do something
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not using built in test runners? Btw `type.GetTypes()`shouldn't compile. what is the CLR type of the variable `type`?

Comment: Want the test to be executed by testing team as well, who don't have access to visual studio.

Comment: Turns out that you can use [VS test agent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7746926/2530848) or simply use nunit; it comes with a test runner.

Comment: I've closed your question being duplicate of the above mentioned one. Hope the related question should help. If you disagree with the duplicate, drop a comment here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the tool. But can you please tell wats wrong with the code and why it is not working

Comment: You've missed typeof keyword here `if (item.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute))`. Also I see several things which could cause compiler error. I believe this isn't the actual code. To be able to help, we need actual code.

Comment: I have the typeof in my code. Sorry about the typo. This is almost the same code I have in my utility

Comment: I got the problem resolved. The issue was due to TestingAssembly was built with a different version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.dll, than the one referred in my utility.