# Is it possible to run MSTest on a remoted server without installing VS2013 or VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, automation, mstest

I have an automation test project written by C# and Selenium. I just want to try having it run by MSTest on a remote server so that I can integrate it with my CI server and have it run after every new change submits. I am not using TFS and I don't want to install VS on server, due to big memory consumption. Just wonder whether there is a way to get MSTest working by copying all MSTest related file to server instead of installing VS.

I have tried a few solutions on google. None of them works. Probably they are setups for VS2012 or below but I tried against VS2013 and VS2015. And the error message is "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". Don't know if it is the problem of my project or missing file for MSTest.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio
http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/05/running-mstest-without-visual-studio.html

Comment: did you try those out?

Comment: Yes. I have tried this out. And that's where I got error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. I've tried following steps from others just as you mentioned you tried and none of them worked. I always ended up installing the test framework.

Comment: What do you mean by installing the test framework? Do you mean install visual studio? I am using Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework.

Comment: There is no reliable way to avoid installing binaries from Visual Studio. The following links give links for agent downloads to install.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio

Comment: Yeah. I have checked out this link before. The agent still requires a fair amount of disk space. I was hesitated to install it so I came here to see if there is any better solution. Now I may just go ahead and install it. Thanks for your help!